# What JavaScript interpreter does Polkit use to interpret rules.d files?

Tags: polkit, javascript

What JavaScript interpreter does Polkit use to interpret rules.d files?

The source code at time of writing links to a defuct Wikipedia heading ["ECMAScript.2C_5th_Edition"](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/polkit/polkit/blob/8f0ef12901d36d1237a28a9abea509daef873feb/docs/man/polkit.xml#L506), however that would only be the specification the interpreter is written to, not the specific implementation that is being used to interpret polkit rule files.

Knowing what and how a javascript interpreter embeded in an authorization system is used would be nice to declare clearly. to disambiguate details such as where the interpreter is being embedding, what is sharing the runtime, when rules files functions are interpreted, if they are being interpreted asynchronously etc; clearly would be nice too.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably Mozilla's implementation.

On my Centos 7 machine:

```
% ldd /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd | grep js
        libmozjs-17.0.so => /lib64/libmozjs-17.0.so (0x00007f7c25d9f000)

% rpm -qif /lib64/libmozjs-17.0.so
Name        : mozjs17
Version     : 17.0.0
Release     : 20.el7
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Sun May 13 09:40:16 2018
Group       : Development/Languages
Size        : 4045213
License     : GPLv2+ or LGPLv2+ or MPLv1.1
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Wed Apr 25 07:27:32 2018, Key ID 24c6a8a7f4a80eb5
Source RPM  : mozjs17-17.0.0-20.el7.src.rpm
Build Date  : Tue Apr 10 20:33:07 2018
Build Host  : x86-01.bsys.centos.org
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Packager    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>
Vendor      : CentOS
URL         : http://www.mozilla.org/js/
Summary     : JavaScript interpreter and libraries
Description :
JavaScript is the Netscape-developed object scripting language used in millions
of web pages and server applications worldwide. Netscape's JavaScript is a
superset of the ECMA-262 Edition 3 (ECMAScript) standard scripting language,
with only mild differences from the published standard.
```

Comment: thank you for your insights! On a "Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa" install, I didn't see an `js` libs linked, `libgobject` was the only `j` match. Currious

Comment: @ThorSummoner on Ubuntu (and by extension Linux Mint), Polkit hasn't been updated to the version that supports JavaScript rules (it's still 0.105, 0.106 is where JS rules were added). So they don't need to link to a js library there.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like polkit now uses duktape ( https://duktape.org/ ) for executing JavaScript:

```
nu ❯ paru -Qi polkit
Name            : polkit
Version         : 122-1
Description     : Application development toolkit for controlling system-wide privileges
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/polkit/polkit
Licenses        : LGPL
...
Depends On      : duktape  expat  glib2  pam  systemd
...

~
nu ❯ paru -Qi duktape
Name            : duktape
Version         : 2.7.0-6
Description     : Embeddable Javascript engine
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : https://duktape.org/
Licenses        : MIT
...
```

From the website, it looks like duktape 2.6.0 had implemented a good chunk of ECMAScript 2015 and 2016, but I suppose you'd probably want to run your rules through duktape directly with some sort of test harness (or even the REPL on the website) to double-check that your rules aren't doing anything beyond it

Answer (score 0):

Actually both existing answers are somewhat correct. Polkit actually supports both `mozjs` and `duktape` as its JS interpreter, configurable at compile time. So the answer today is "it depends on your distribution".

Support for `duktape` as an alternate interpreter was added in early 2022 in [this MR](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/polkit/polkit/-/commit/c7fc4e1b61f0fd82fc697c19c604af7e9fb291a2), and it seems like all three major base distributions (tested: ArchLinux, Debian 12, Fedora 38) have switched to it. However this may not be the case for older releases and/or stability-oriented distributions (notably, RHEL 9).

---

So the definitive way to find out for your distro is to check the libs that `/usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd` links against, as suggested by @StephenHarris. You can run this oneliner:

```bash
ldd /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd | grep -E '(mozjs|duktape)'
```

And if it prints nothing, it means the `polkit` package you have was built without JS rule support.